# What is the difference between "allocatable cpu" and "allocated cpu limit" on a GKE cluster node

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, cpu-usage

When I do

```
kubectl describe node <node-name> | grep cpu
```

on my Google Kubernetes Cluster I do get

```
cpu:                        1
cpu:                        940m
cpu                        709m (75%)   2156m (229%)
```

My question is about the difference of the last number in line two (`940m`) and the last number in line three (`2156m`). The latter is the the limit of the allocated resources:

```
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource                   Requests     Limits
  --------                   --------     ------
  cpu                        709m (75%)   2156m (229%)
```

The former is the allocatable cpu

```
Allocatable:
 attachable-volumes-gce-pd:  128
 cpu:                        940m
```

What is the difference between these two numbers? Why are they not the same? And what is the relevant limit that decides if a pod can be started on the node or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allocatable is the amount of resources available to the pods to consume, 940m cpu in your example.

The allocated limit is the sum of all the pod limits defined in pods running on the node. The allocatable and the resource requested are more useful

Comment: What do you mean by „more useful“?

Comment: The allocatable tells you how many resources can be used by pods, the resource requested show how much of the allocatable has been assigned to pods (not necessarily used). Whereas the allocated limit does not really give you useful information, the total can be much much greater than the total resources on a node and you still may not run into any issues at all

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell

- 940m is the number of millicores your pod uses.
- 2156m is the number of millicores usable before killing your pod for excessive use of CPU.

More in depth, it is how the architecture is designed, when a process requests memory and CPU takes into consideration the type of machine (bare metal or cloud, and which cloud) how node pools were defined and how much resources those node pools have to provide them to the pods (deployment sets and so forth); this also takes into consideration overhead and system usage.

If you would like to know more I am adding to links to this answer so you can check them out, they are quite useful.

Have an awesome day!

[1] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture

[2] https://unofficial-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/